# How to Copy paste data range from Excel to powerpoint slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to prepare code to copy and paste excel data range from excel sheet to powerpoint slide but I am able to paste images only.

Please help with the suitable code. The code I am using is as follows:

```
Sub WorkbooktoPowerPoint()

    Dim pp As Object
    Dim PPPres As Object
    Dim PPSlide As Object
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    pp.Visible = True
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:J31")

    Rng.Copy

    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)

    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject
    PPSlide.Shapes(1).Select
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, True
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 65
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 7.2
    pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 700

    pp.Activate
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set pp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to try my suggestion below? If it is working, kindly mark the answer as "Accepted" so that others may benefit from learning of this method.

Answer (score 1):

It still surprises me that many of the `PasteSpecial` options are not available form the clipboard or in PowerPoint generally.  I think there is a way around this using a different method.  Instead of:

```
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteOLEObject
```

Try using this method:

```
PPSlide.Parent.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
```

I am not certain of the correct `idMso` argument to use but I would start with that, it looks like it works the way I would expect it to:

**PowerPoint Result**

[image]

**Excel Table Example**

[image]

If not, there are several others that might be worth checking:

- PasteSourceFormatting
- PasteDestinationTheme
- PasteAsEmbedded
- PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting
- PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle

This method is not as well-documented compared to many other methods. The `Application.CommandBars` [property reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744604(v=office.14).aspx) has nary a mention of the `ExecuteMso` method, which I found some information about here (and on SO where I have seen it used once or twice before):

The full list of *idMso* parameters to explore, which come as part of a rather large executable for use with fluent ribbon UI design, current for Office 2013 I believe:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=727

Comment: David, I have tried using the above ExecuteMso methods and they did not run. I have MS office 2013. Are there any others methods to copy excel range as Embedded onject?
Thanks

Comment: @KanikeVamshiKrishna please ask a new question, rather than using the comments on someone else's question. Asking a new question will allow you to provide important details, example of your code, etc.  If you do that, you can tag me in the comment there and I will try to assist if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Another method for getting the data from Excel to PPT slides without VBA code also possible.

Note: save both workbook and PPT file in one location.

Step 1: Copy excel data / table

Step 2: Go to Power point slides

Step 3: Select Paste special option

Step 4: Select "Paste Link" radio button

Step 5: Click on Ok

Then save the files then change the data in excel, now it will automatically copy the data based linking the connection.

Hope this option helps.

Thanks,
Gourish

Answer (score 0):

To take an Excel range and paste it into a PowerPoint Application, requires breaking down **the process into a few different parts**. Looking at your code, we can break it down to the following components:

- Create an instance of PowerPoint.
- Create your slide & presentation.
- Create a reference to the range you want to export & then copy it.
- Align the shape to the desired dimensions.
- Finally, release your objects from memory.

**I am assuming that you want this code left as late-binding**, but there are also sections of your code that will cause issues because you are treating it like it was written in early-binding.

Also, I have a YouTube video on this topic, so feel free to watch the series if you want to do a more complicated paste or if you're working with multiple Excel Ranges.

**Link to Playlist:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcFcktZ0wnNlFcSydYb8bI1AclQ4I38VN**

**SECTION ONE: DECLARE THE VARIABLES**

Here we will just create all the variables we need in our script.

```
'Declare PowerPoint Variables
 Dim PPTApp As Object
 Dim PPTPres As Object
 Dim PPTSlide As Object

'Dim Excel Variables
 Dim ExcRng As Range
```

**SECTION TWO: CREATE A NEW INSTANCE OF POWERPOINT**

This will create a new PowerPoint application, make it visible and make it the active window.

```
'Create a new PowerPoint Application and make it visible.
 Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
     PPTApp.Visible = True
     PPTApp.Activate
```

**SECTION THREE: CREATE A NEW PRESENTATION & SLIDE**

This will add a new presentation to the PowerPoint Application, create a new slide in the presentation and set the layout as a blank layout.

```
'Create a new Presentation
Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

'Create a new Slide
Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(1, 12) '<<< THIS 12 MEANS A BLANK LAYOUT.
```

**SECTION FOUR: CREATE A REFERENCE TO THE EXCEL RANGE & COPY IT**

This will set a reference to our Excel range we want to copy and copy it.

```
'Set a reference to the range
Set ExcRng = Range("B1:J31")

'Copy Range
ExcRng.Copy
```

**SECTION FOUR: PASTE IN SLIDE AS OLEOBJECT**

This will paste the range in the slide and set a reference to it.

```
'Paste the range in the slide
 SET PPTShape = PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(10) '<<< 10 means OLEOBJECT
```

**SECTION FIVE: ALIGN THE SHAPE**

This will select the shape and set the dimensions of it.

```
'Select the shape.
PPTSlide.Shapes(PPTSlide.Shapes.Count).Select

'Set the Dimensions of the shape.
With PPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Top = 65
    .Left = 7.2
    .Width = 700
End With
```

**SECTION SIX: RELEASE OBJECTS FROM MEMORY**

This will release the objects from memory.

```
'Erase Objects from memory.
Set PPTApp = Nothing
Set PPTSlide = Nothing
Set PPTShape = Nothing
```

In full, this is how your code will now look:

```
Sub ExportRangeToPowerPoint_Late()

    Dim PPTApp As Object
    Dim PPTPres As Object
    Dim PPTSlide As Object
    Dim PPTShape As Object

    Dim ExcRng As Range

    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set PPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        PPTApp.Visible = True
        PPTApp.Activate

    'Create a new Presentation
    Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Add

    'Create a new Slide
    Set PPTSlide = PPTPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

    'Set a reference to the range
    Set ExcRng = Range("B1:J31")

    'Copy Range
    ExcRng.Copy

    'Paste the range in the slide
    Set PPTShape = PPTSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(10)

    'Select the shape.
    PPTSlide.Shapes(PPTSlide.Shapes.Count).Select

    'Set the Dimensions of the shape.
    With PPTApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
        .Top = 65
        .Left = 7.2
        .Width = 700
    End With

    'Erase Objects from memory.
    Set PPTApp = Nothing
    Set PPTSlide = Nothing
    Set PPTShape = Nothing

End Sub
```