# When pasting into powerPoint from Excel using vba, only PasteMetafilePicture works

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

This one has me pretty confused. I have written a code that creates a pivot table in excel. It then creates a new PowerPoint and adjusts the formatting. Finally, I am hoping to take the pivot table from excel, copy it, and paste it into the PowerPoint file. I want to be able to edit it so a bitmap, picture, GIF, etc. will not work.

Everything works fine until I paste the pivot table into excel. This pastes a picture into the PowerPoint, no problem:

```
pt.TableRange1.Copy
newPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
```

where pt is the pivot table, and newPPT is the PowerPoint.Application

This, however, does not work.

```
pt.TableRange1.Copy
newPPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPasteHTML)
```

Nothing pastes at all. I have tried zooming out, moving all objects around because maybe it pasted behind everything but no luck. Any idea why this is happening?

Also, when I paste from the clipboard after the code has run, without re-copying the pivot table, it pastes no problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
pt.TableRange1.Copy
newPPT.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML
```

I don't know why it doesn't using the shapes paste special, but this is a workaround.

Anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Nope, but that's a good workaround. Alternatively, you could try using the `CommandBars.ExecuteMSO` method, which in my experience has been more reliable for pasting in to PPT. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24644730/1467082