# Insert Excel Content in Powerpoint. Error Message: Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here

Tags: excel, vba, image, insert, powerpoint

I am trying to copy data from my Excel sheet and paste it as a picture in a presentation.

Often an Error message displays saying:

> Shapes (unknown member): invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.

Sometimes it appears earlier sometimes later, sometimes it even works and all slides get created.

My code is the following:

```
Public Function createPP(workbookName As String, Worksheet As String, title As String) As Boolean
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer, lastCol As Integer, lastRow1 As Integer, lastCol1 As Integer
    Dim Worksheet2 As String

    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate

    Sheets(Worksheet).Select
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lastCol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Sheets(Worksheet2).Select
    lastRow1 = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    lastCol1 = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add
    ppPres.ApplyTemplate (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\HPETheme.thmx")
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutCustom)
    ppSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = title
    ppSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = "per SPL per month" '& vbNewLine & "presented by Isabelle Schmiedel"
    ppSlide.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange = "Isabelle Schmiedel"
    x = 2

    For counter = 2 To lastRow - 1
        Set rng = Workbooks(workbookName).Sheets(Worksheet).Range("A" & counter & ":J" & counter + 24)
        Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(x, 11)
        ppSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange = Sheets(Worksheet).Cells(counter, 1)
       ppSlide.Select

        rng.Copy

        ppSlide.Shapes.Paste

        counter = counter + 25
        x = x + 1
    Next counter
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
```

Try this to copy the table/range directly::

```
ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
```

Or possibly:

```
ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
```

If you prefer a *picture*, then use this:

```
ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteAsPicture"
```

Explanation:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644730/1467082

If for some reason the font size isn't preserved, you can do something like this

```
Dim tRow as Long, tCol as Long, shp as Object, tbl as Object, tblCell as Object

Set shp = ppSlide.Shapes(ppSlide.Shapes.Count)
Set tbl = shp.Table
For tRow = 1 to tbl.Rows.Count
    For tCol = 1 to tbl.Columns.Count
        Set tblCell = tbl.Cell(tRow, tCol)
        # Assign each cell the same font size from corresponding cell in Excel range:
        tblCell.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = rng(tRow, tCol).Font.Size
    Next
Next
```

You could also try something like this, which is a bit hacky, but might be faster than cell iteration:

```
Set shp = ppSlide.Shapes(ppSlide.Shapes.Count)
shp.Select
While shp.Table.Cell(1,1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size < 12
    ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FontSizeIncrease"
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this help. Its working better, a error message does not arrive instantly but, unfortunately it's still not working properly. I am getting the run-time error: Method 'ExecuteMso' of object '_CommandBars' failed.

Comment: The Line: ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
But I solved it by letting Excel wait for a little time before contining, somehow that helped. 
Nevertheless do you maybe know how I can insert the Table in FontSize 12? It always paste it in size 10 although my table content has size 12. I thought "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting" might work for that but it didn't.

Comment: No, that is strange, I tried copy/paste a "Table" as well as just a simple range of cells, and both attempts successfully preserved the formatting (font & size, etc.) from Excel. I'm not sure what would cause that behavior. It is not difficult to change font size/etc, but you basically will need to do a loop over each row/column (cell) in the PPT Table, and change the font size accordingly. I'll add that to my answer...

Comment: No not that I know. I think you need to identify why PPT is not behaving as expected (i.e., source formatting should be preserved). This might be a topic for a new question. Perhaps you have a POTX or THMX file which is causing a conflict? IDK...

Comment: I have one alternative suggestion but that makes some assumptions which might not always hold true.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help! 
Oh which suggestion do you have? 
My guess would be that Excel might automatically resize it so it does better fit into the slide.

Comment: NP. It does seem like there should be a way to *select* the entire table, and *apply* a uniform font to it (you can do this manually, so I feel like it should be do-able with VBA, but I don't see anything in the PPT object model that would actually do this).

Comment: The second approach is working perfect and much quicker. Thanks alot for your help!! It's fine that way.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433826/error-pasting-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-vba ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below one 
sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0

or

sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteShape