# How to paste data from Excel into PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i came across some code from the msdn.microsoft.com website, but I am getting an error when trying to test it. This code is literally their example code. Code below:

```
Sub ReplaceText()

Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
Dim oTmpRng As TextRange

Set oSld = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes

    Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
    Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:="Name Here", _
        Replacewhat:="TESTTEST", WholeWords:=True)

Next oShp

End Sub
```

The error occurs in the `Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange` line, and the error is "the specified value is out of range". Anyone know why I am getting this error, and how I can avoid it? This is in the VBA editor in Powerpoint, and I have the ppt presentation open

Comment: This looks promising - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506703/how-to-copy-paste-data-range-from-excel-to-powerpoint-slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some shapes don't have textframes (lines/connectors/OLE objects, etc) so you want to test for that first. And then the shape may have a text frame but no text in it, so you test for that. And THEN you can assign the textrange to a variable:

```
If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
  If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
    Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! I actually figured that out on my own, but I guess it's good to have the answer available. Maybe I should have "answered my own question".

Answer (score 1):

If you have ppt already opened, do not create but get object. Instead of:

```
Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
```

you should have

```
Set oPPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
```

Then, don't open presentation, but use this already opened and active:

```
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation
```

If it has only one slide, you can access shapes in it with the following code

```
Dim sh As PowerPoint.Shape
For Each sh In oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes
   'do something with sh
Next sh
```

The property you are looking for is probably sh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, but make experiments with Intellisense.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate your answer. I think this is definitely the property that I am looking for. However, I am getting an error when trying to test around with it. I edited my question above to show what I'm talking about. If you have any insight to what's going on, that would be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have some shape without text. You could use conditional instruction If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then ... End If to exclude shapes without text like logos or charts.